# How can I assign the UIBarButtonSystemItemAction icon to a UIButton?

Tags: iphone, uibutton

I have a UIButton within a UITableViewCell and I would like to assign the standard 'Action' icon to this button.

This icon is normally associated with a UIBarButtonItem by assigning the icon to UIBarButtonSystemItemAction, however I cannot add a UIBarButtonItem into the UITableViewCell's view and therefore I would like to know if it's possible to assign this icon to a plain UIButton?

Thanks,

Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible through the current 3.1.3 (or lower) iPhone SDK.  You will have to google around for the image, or make it yourself, and place it on the button.

Comment: Thanks, for the feedback.  At least now I know which approach I have to take.

Comment: Anyone know if it's possible with iOS 6?